# Access non-namespaced model from inside namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a namespaced model "quiz" under Student, and I need to access a model without a namespace of the same name. I can't do Quiz.all because it's in the namespace, how do I get the Quiz stuff for the model without the namespace?

My model is `class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base`
The model is in app/models/quiz.rb
My controller is `class Student::QuizzesController < ApplicationController`
The controller is in app/controllers/student/quizzes_controller.rb

I also have another model that's a namespaced version of quiz. `class Student::Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base`, and when I generated the model it made a student.rb model in the app/models directory that has this in it.

```
module Student

  def self.table_name_prefix

    'student_'

  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ::Quiz to explicitly refer to the toplevel Quiz constant.